# Can't I send a "docx" document through DocusSign e-signature API?

Tags: docusignapi

When I send a docx file, I'm receiving an error message that says:

{"errorCode":"UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT","message":"Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1;Fluig - Novos Processos.docx). Error: PDF header signature not found."}

I'm using JSON simple request.

These are the document params I'm sending to DocuSign:

params : {
"status":"created",
"emailSubject":String(emailSubject),
"documents":[
{
"documentBase64": String(base64),
"documentId":"1",
"fileExtension": String(fileExtension),
"name":String(fileName)
}
]
}

Comment: What does your FileExtension parameter parse out to be? If it's not `docx` that's likely the problem. To confirm, you might use API logging to capture what it looks like from the DocuSign side.

Answer (score 0):

As Drew says in his comment, the key is to set the `fileExtension` attribute to `docx` (not to `.docx`)

Use [API Logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see exactly what your app is sending to DocuSign.

If this doesn't solve your problem, then update (edit) your **question** to add the output from the API logging.